# ie 10 css 3d transform behaves differently

Tags: css, transform, internet-explorer-10

I was trying to implement the "translateZ" transform function in IE10 preview and came across an issue.

So it only works properly if the "direct" parent of the transformed node has the "-ms-perspective" property and does not work if the parent's parent has got the "-ms-perspective" property set up.

Can anyone suggest if this is a bug and if there is a workaround.
For example it does not work if in the following code I apply "-ms-perspective" to "div1" and try rotateZ on div3 .

```
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">
        Parent
        <div class="div3">
            Child
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears to work just fine for me in Internet Explorer 10.0.8400.0:

```
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">
        Parent
        <div  class="div3">
            Child Rotated
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Along with the following CSS:

```
.div1 {
    margin: 25px 100px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    -ms-perspective: 500px;
}

.div3 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: orange;
    -ms-transform: rotateZ(30deg);
}
```

Produces the following effect:

[image]

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/NKZw6/

Comment: this worked for me also.but the translateZ is not working fine.on continuosly changing the translateZ values there is no visible effect in this case but there is a visible effect when the perspective is on div2